# Are coronavirus-like spikes only seen in viruses?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, immune-system, coronavirus

Are there any natural proteins or cells (or anything) made by the human body with [spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peplomer) like those of Covid-19?

I know that there have been no serious side effects reported from the Covid-19 vaccine, but I am wondering
what theoretical interference might occur if the immune system started attacking any similarly-spiked
thing that it found.

Comment: The immune system doesn't recognize foreign invaders based on their outward shape; it recognizes them based on the presence of a specific protein.

Comment: @CareyGregory Ok, let me broaden the question then to "Are there any natural proteins made by the human body which are similar to the Covid-19 spike protein?"

Comment: Sure, by all means edit your question to be more along those lines. I think that will make it a better question. And if it doesn't get answered here, you might try Biology.SE because the answer will depend on the fine points of how the immune system recognizes proteins and just how "similar" they have to be. But don't cross-post. Just try one site at a time.